# Snake Game Values Broken

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm having a problem with my snake game it's coded in js and I'm trying to figure out how to make a menu where you can change the values, the value doesn't get logged in the console and it does not appear in the game.

https://jsfiddle.net/Faxtixe/duq6ba3x/3/

```js
class Apple {
    constructor() {
        let isTouching

        while (true) {
            isTouching = false;
            this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width / snake.size) * snake.size
            this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height / snake.size) * snake.size

            for (let i = 0; i < snake.tail.length; i++) {
                if (this.x == snake.tail[i].x && this.y == snake.tail[i].y) {
                    isTouching = false
                }
            }

            var tb1 = document.getElementById("setInterval").value // fps/Interval var curruntly not working
            var tb2 = document.getElementById("thisColor").value // color var also curruntly not working
            console.log(tb1);
            console.log(tb2);


            this.size = snake.size
            this.color = tb2.value // here is the color of the food
```

And
[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihcjQ.png)

```
window.onload = () => {
    gameLoop()
}
```

```js
function gameLoop() {
    setInterval(show, 1000/tb1.value) // here is our fps value
}
```

This is the HTML code

```html
<form>
    <label for="setInterval">Speed/FPS:</label>
    <input type="text" id="setInterval" name="setInterval"><br><br>
    <label for="this.color">Food Color:</label>
    <input type="text" id="thisColor" name="thisColor"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lPki.png)

Comment: There's not enough here for us to see the issue.  We need to see the scope of the variables and the `gameLoop` function. I see one of the lines is `this.color = tb2.value`, is this all within a class?

Comment: I fixed it and the `this.color = tb1.value` was already shown you've must have missed it.

Comment: Where is `gameLoop()` defined? why does `tb1` have a value property? You should show more of the code...

Comment: @Faxtixe You need to add a working example using a website like JSFiddle so people can help you. What you posted here isn't enough to figure out what you need.

Comment: A working example in a codesandbox or similar would help your cause a lot.

Comment: i added a working example already

Answer (score 0):

At minimum you need to initialize the tb1 variable.

```
const tb1 = document.getElementById("setInterval")
```

In the form you need to have some initial value, given that you start your game running when the page loads and before the user would have a chance to set that variable.  There are other problems you will need to solve to actually get things working as you intend, but at least this will help you get past the error in your question.

```
<input type="text" id="setInterval" name="setInterval" value="50"><br><br>
```